# How do I removing a created element before appendChild

Tags: javascript

In a loop I am creating some image elements through

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "c.php?t=icon&c=" + list[cnt];
```

and then I wait for a successful `img.onload` before `appendChild(img)`.

However, should there be a problem that calls `img.onerror` how would I go about removing the `img` element? Seeing as `appendChild` has not been called, I cannot remove it through `img.parentNode.removeChild(img)`.

Comment: If `appendChild` hasn't been called yet, what are you trying to remove?

Comment: If you are trying to deference the variable you can set the value of the variable to `null` `img = null`